# Very heavy php-fpm processes

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php7, php-fpm

I have problems with heavy `php-fpm` on a server. Here an excerpt from top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 7631 <user>       20   0  583996  88932  72300 S  32.9  0.3  10:32.62 php-fpm7.2
```

I don't really understand how these processes can run so long.

I have `memory_limit = 80M` and as `max_execution_time = 60`. Can anyone tell me how these processes can run for so long? :(

Comment: Where (in which file) you have set these limits?

Comment: @pa4080 these settings i have in my php.ini